# R logical(0) in sapply

Tags: r, sapply

Why does

> sapply(c(TRUE, FALSE, logical(0)), length)

return

> [1] 1 1

In other words, how come the logical(0) is ignored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what @PenelopeHopHop said is true however she didn't explain the error. the error is rising from the `c()` function combines it's arguments and because `logical(0)` is empty it doesn't get combined making the input of the sappply of length 2 thus the output is of length 2.

```r
c(TRUE, FALSE, logical(0))
#> [1]  TRUE FALSE
```

What you can be achieved if you replace `c()` with `list()`

```r
list(TRUE, FALSE, logical(0))
#> [[1]]
#> [1] TRUE
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] FALSE
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> logical(0)
sapply(list(TRUE, FALSE, logical(0)), length)
#> [1] 1 1 0
```

And instead of using `sapply(..., length)` use `lengths` function as it does what you aim to achieve.

```r
lengths(list(TRUE, FALSE, logical(0)))
#> [1] 1 1 0
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Is it reasonable to think that this is a ludicrous source thing of R to do? I mean, it is silently dropping an element of a vector. No warning.

Comment: @PejoPhylo as I explained the it is not ludicrous as the `c()` function is *combines its arguments to form a vector.  All arguments are coerced to a common type which is the type of the returned value, and all attributes except names are removed.* so it's combining the `TRUE`, `FALSE` and an empty element (`logical(0)`) thus only `TRUE` and `FALSE` should remain.

Answer (score 2):

look at the logical function help, you have : logical(length = 0). You'r creating a logical object of length 0 (empty)

I can't comment so I edit.
It is because `c(TRUE, FALSE, logical(0))` is an object of length 2, since the last element is empty. Then `sapply` returns an object of length 2.

Comment: I don't understand how that explains that I'm ignoring the logical(0) in sapply. I'd expect to get [1] 1 1 0 returned from the sapply call